# where would be a sane place to put the jre folder?

Tags: linux, debian, installation, java

I'm installing a debian server.

The server needs a specific version of java, so I'm installing from the self-extracting file.

But I'm new to the linux world and I want to put the jre in a place that will make sense to me when i'm better acquainted with the folder structure. where should I put it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could install it under /opt. That would keep it separate from the system directories where a Debian supplied version of Java might be installed.

Comment: under opt, with its version information, such jdk1.6.0_13, and then a simlinks to whatever cleaner names you want for it.  You might even add simlinks to /etc/aternatives for executables

Answer (score 1):

Yes /opt would also allow you to be more aware of what is interacting with it and avoid any unintentional upgrades or alterations to the installation.

Answer (score 0):

This is how we layout out sdk's

```
/opt/java/sdk/current -> /opt/java/sdk/sun/i386/current
/opt/java/sdk/sun/i386/current -> /opt/java/sdk/sun/i386/1.6
/opt/java/sdk/sun/i386/1.6 -> /opt/java/sdk/sun/i386/jdk1.6.0_13
```

and so on.